# Why do my ArrayList of Arraylist values change back after I set them?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, iteration

I'm working with an ArrayList of Arraylists of Arraylists of ArrayLists, unfortunately. I'm very new to Java, so this could be a simple mistake on my part (I'm used to Perl). I'm troubleshooting some code where I've built the full structure of the empty ArrayList^4 (it represents a fixed number of data fields that never change, but have values that are modified) and then try to ingest a file, setting the nested values using ArrayList.get() and ArrayList.set(). Here's the code-- lines are read in from a file (into the ArrayList lines) and iterated upon to be added piecewise to the ArrayList^4 (called DB).

The general format of input data read into the "lines" ArrayList is approximately as follows-- sorry it's hard on the eyes. Each 0 can be any string:

```
ID  0.0-0.0 0.0-0.0 0.0-0.0 0.0-0.0 0.0-0.0
```

DB is the final ArrayList^4, four nested array lists that all contain certain numbers of placeholder strings. It's built by sequentially adding ArrayLists of zeroes to ArrayList^2, then those to an Arraylist^3, which is the Line added to DB. The input data is broken down by various separators and used to replace these placeholder strings.

```
ArrayList<String> Single = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Single.add("0"); }

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Squared = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    Squared.add(Single);
    Squared.add(Single);

ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> Line = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
    Line.add(Squared);
    //repeat to make 5 items in list
```

The separators for the data are technically the \n, \t, -, and . in that order.

I use j+1 in the one line because the first column of the input file (six columns total) is just a title (and is hence added to the ArrayList "info"), so it's skipped for the rest of the data processing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < linesSize; i ++) {
    DB.add(Line); //Line is an ArrayList^3 containing the "empty" values for the given line
    List<String> columns = Arrays.asList(lines.get(i).split("\t"));
    info.add(columns.get(0));
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j ++) {
        List<String> categories = Arrays.asList(columns.get(j+1).split("-"));
        int categoriesSize = categories.size();
        for (int k = 0; k < categoriesSize; k ++) {
            List<String> elements = Arrays.asList(categories.get(k).split(Pattern.quote(".")));
            int elementsSize = elements.size();
            for (int l = 0; l < elementsSize; l ++) {
                String id = elements.get(l);
                //System.out.println("before:" + DB.get(i).get(j).get(k).get(l));
                DB.get(i).get(j).get(k).set(l, id);
                //System.out.println("after:" + DB.get(i).get(j).get(k).get(l) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've included the troubleshooting commented lines because they tell me that the values are being changed back. For example, I'll see

```
Before: 0
After: X
```

but then a few lines down:

```
Before: X
After: 0
```

There's no reason the data should be changing back unless something unexpected is happening in my loop... I've been staring at it for a while to no avail. I've checked all of the Size variables and they seem to be coming out correctly. The output file also prints correctly when I reassemble the data (code not shown). I've also used DB.add(Line) in a separate, prior loop in case it was messing something up, but no dice.

Please let me know if I've missed something! Thanks! I'm also aware there are probably better ways of doing this, but this just has to work; it doesn't have to be particularly efficient or elegant.

Comment: This isn't a minimal reproduce-able example. What is DB?

Comment: When you first use `Columns` and `j` you use `j+1`.  But later you use just `j` when you do a `get`.  It doesn't make sense to me that you can use `j` and `j+1` for the same loop going from `0 to 4` inclusive.  I would think you would either miss something or throw an exception.  But it's hard to determine without some sample data.

Comment: Sorry, that's confusing on my part. The input data file and the DB structure are the same except for the ID column, so the switch between j+1 and j is to line them up. Column index 0 points to name in the input file, but actual data in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What hurts more to the eyes is the use of capitals for variables: 'Single', 'Square', 'Line' should be lowercase according to all Java style guides. But that's not the cause of your issue.

You're adding the same 'line' multiple times to the DB object. You should make a new ArrayList() for every line, otherwise if you add an item to the Line list, it is added for every index 'i'.

Same holds for 'single' and 'squared', you add the same 'single' Arraylist to the 'squared' multiple times instead of adding a new one every time, so those won't be distinct either.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So each instance of "Line" I've been adding shares all its values with the other ones, which is why it's all getting reset?

Comment: no, it does not share, it is the same instance (the same memory position)